# parse data sent by webapi. is IEnumerable a good choice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-8, microsoft-metro, asp.net-web-api

Hello I'm creating WebAPI and a windows8 metro app that communicates with this API.

I'll use simple example

API

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Application

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(this.apiUri.GetUri("content", "Get")))
            {
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
        }
```

Now the variable result is the response from API. But this is a string in form

```
"[\"value1\",\"value2\"]"
```

How can I parse/convert this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy for you to deserialize back using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), in your case:

```
var json = "[\"value1\",\"value2\"]";
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
```

Comment: this is awsome. Can I use this in commercial project ?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's free open source so you can use it in your commercial project

Answer (score 2):

WebAPIs return JSON by default. You can request it to send XML, or use a JSON parser.

Comment: yes I know that it displays me XML when I invoke url directly by webbrowser. But how can I get this JSON or XML via HttpClient in my client app ? webapi method that i shown is default. Didn`t change there nothing

Answer (score 0):

I use my class (MVCClient.cs) in silverlight to communicate with MVC WebAPI.  In your case you'd just want to call :

```
DoGetMessage<string>(yourUrl, new DataDelegateArray<string>(yourCallbackFunction));
```

The lines that you are missing in your code would be :

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
T data = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

Where T is string[].

MVCClient.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
public class MVCClient
    {
        public delegate void DataDelegateArray<T>(T[] objects);
        public delegate void DataDelegate<U>(U obj);

    #region Communication Functions
        public void DoPostMessage<T>(string queryURL, T item, ProcessPOSTResult<T> callback)
        {
            DoPostMessage<T, T>(queryURL, item, callback);
        }

        public void DoPostMessage<TPost, TReply>(string queryURL, TPost item, ProcessPOSTResult<TReply> callback)
        {
#if SILVERLIGHT
            Uri uri = new Uri(queryURL, UriKind.Absolute);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(result =>
                {
                    var req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                    var stream = req.EndGetRequestStream(result);

                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        var data = new
                        {
                            name = item
                        };


                        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TPost));
                        serializer.WriteObject(stream, item);
                        stream.Close();
                    }

                    req.BeginGetResponse((requestResult) =>
                    {
                        var req2 = (HttpWebRequest)requestResult.AsyncState;
                        var response = req2.EndGetResponse(requestResult);
                        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TReply));
                        TReply responseItem = (TReply)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);

                        System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            callback(responseItem);
                        });

                    }, req);
                }, request);

#endif
        }

        public void DoGetMessage<T>(string queryURL, DataDelegateArray<T> callback)
        {
            DoGetMessage<T[]>(queryURL, result => callback(result));
        }

        public void DoGetMessage<T>(string queryURL, DataDelegate<T> callback)
        {
#if SILVERLIGHT
            Uri uri = new Uri(queryURL, UriKind.Absolute);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Accept = "text/json";
            request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
            {
                var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
                var stream = response.GetResponseStream();

                if (stream != null)
                {
                    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
                    T data = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        callback(data);
                    });
                }
                else
                    System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        callback(default(T));
                    });
            }, null);
#endif
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: yeah that was that what I was looking for :) var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TReply));
                        TReply responseItem = (TReply)serializer.ReadObject(responseStream);
this code is the core that I've needed